# Strange behavior of the context.fillText() in HTML5/Canvas

Tags: html, html5-canvas

I have a little problem with the context.fillText() function.

When I call a function using it, it doesn't draw the text, unless I call it after I start the "mainloop". All the context.fillRect()s called in the same function work perfectly.

Here is my code. I write a couple of comment to highlight where it works or doesn't work.

```
var pause = true;

function draw () {
    if ( !pause ) {
        redraw_everything();
    }
    else {
        draw_popup(); // WORKAROUND
    }
}

function draw_popup ( text ) {
    ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
    ctx.fillRect ( _x, _y, _w, _h );
    ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
    ctx.fillRect ( _in_x, _in_y, _in_w, _in_h );

    ctx.font = theight + "pt Orbitron";
    twidth = ctx.measureText ( text ).width;

    ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
    ctx.fillText ( text, _tx, _ty );  /** Draw the text */
    ctx.restore();
}

function init() {
    canvas = document.getElementById ( 'tutorial' );
    ctx = canvas.getContext ( '2d' );

    pause = false;
    draw();
    pause = true;
    setInterval ( 'draw()', 20 );
    draw_popup ( 'PacMan' ); // DOESN'T WORK

    tutorial = document.getElementsByTagName( 'body' )[ 0 ];
    tutorial.onkeypress = function ( e ) {
        var c = String.fromCharCode( e.charCode ).toLowerCase();
        if ( c == 'p' ) {
             draw_popup ( 'Pause' ); // IT WORKS
        }
    }
}
```

You can find the full source code [here](https://github.com/HoX/Simple-Sample/tree/master/HTML5/pacman)

*UPDATE*: As requested, I made a shorter example (not tested).

Comment: Can you isolate your problem to a short example?

Comment: Done. I hope is enough short and enough understandable

Comment: I found the problem. I am using a font from the Google Webfont collection. The first time i use it, the font isn't loaded yet, so it doesn't write. The following requests have the font already loaded, therefore i work

Comment: @AndreaCarron: you should post that as an answer, I think, so that the question doesn't appear unanswered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I am using a font from the Google Webfont collection. The first time i use it, the font isn't loaded yet, so it doesn't write. The following requests have the font already loaded, therefore i work